# Only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars: Because of Diag or Rowsum?

Tags: python, computer-vision, cluster-analysis, typeerror, scalar

I have two very simple classes: ncut and cluster. Cluster calls a few methods from ncut. You can see the code below. However, when I run cluster.py, I get a TypeError stating that "only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars." I'm pretty new to Python (a few days), and while I've tried to find other similar situations on Stack Overflow, I still can't seem to fix this.

The exact error I get is:

> line 62, in cluster D = diag(1/sqrt(rowsum+1e-6)) TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.

At line 62, I have variable D:

```
# Create Laplacian matrix
rowsum = (sum(abs(S), axis=0))
D = diag(1 / sqrt(rowsum + 1e-6))
L = dot(D, dot(S,D))

# Compute eigenvector of L
U,sigma,V = linalg.svd(L)
```

I have a feeling that this has something to do with incompatibility stemming from diag or rowsum. Please let me know how I can fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm presuming you have imported Numpy?

Comment: Yes -- I have imported Numpy, Scipy, and matplotlib in both classes.

Comment: @acs254 may you please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  Thank you.